# How to unpack a chrome theme?

Tags: google-chrome, compression, themes

How to unpack a packed chrome theme(*.crx)? Their FAQ states how to pack, but not how to unpack.

Answer (score 17):

On Mac OS X, you can use `unzip` to decompress the `.crx` file:

```
unzip extension.crx
```

Here's the result:

[image: unzip result]

Comment: works on linux too

Comment: works on mac too

Answer (score 14):

I got the solution: apparently, a .crx file is just a renamed .zip file. Additionally, when you install it, the theme is decompressed into the chrome install directory...

Comment: Not quite; it’s not *just* a renamed ZIP. Open one in a hex-editor and see that there is clearly a proprietary header. That said, yes, it is basically a ZIP, and can be opened in most ZIP-capable programs. I prefer [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: @Synetech is correct, the file header contains a public key and signature.  Google's [.crx Package Format](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx.html) page explains this.  In practice, you should be able to extract a .crx file with `unzip`, and it will ignore the extra bytes.  If you do end up needing to chop off the header first, running unzip -l will show you how many (**N+1** bytes with tail).  For example: If `unzip -l` complains with **warning [file.crx]: ***306*** extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile**, then run: `tail -c +307 file.crx > /tmp/file.crx; unzip -l /tmp/file.crx`

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's more than a zip. When you `unzip -l` you'll see a message:

> warning [extension.crx]:  306 extra bytes at beginning or within
>   zipfile

So the crx file is 306 bytes of something plus a zip archive.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome extension install directory:

Mac:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions
```

Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Comment: Best solution out of them all. This worked for me, none of the others did.

Answer (score 3):

This video explains everything about what a .crx is. In addition to a .zip holding all the extension's resources, it includes a public key and a signature, to ensure integrity and authenticity of the file:  [Antony Sargent explains .crx files Hosted by: youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNkfs8-uRTE&feature=player_detailpage#t=110s)

The details of the .crx [package format are published here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yep aviraldg is right. rename it to a .zip and use your favorite extraction tool. XPIs for firefox, etc, are the same process.